# Is it dangerous if I expose my database schema in an open source project?

Tags: python, database, open-source, schema, database-schema

I am writing myself a blog in python, and am to put it up to GitHub.

One of the file in this project will be a script that create the required tables in DB at the very beginning. Since I've gonna put this file on a public repository, I expose all DB structure.

Is it dangerous if I do so?

If yes, I am thinking of an alternative to put column names in a separate config file and not upload column names of my blog. What are others ways of avoiding exposing schemas?

Comment: Security by obscurity is not going to keep you safe. Publish the schema.

Comment: Most people are not malicious, you'll find that more people want to help than to exploit any weaknesses in your code.

Comment: "Dangerous"?  How so, especially in a self-professed open source project?  What harm are you imagining?

Comment: Martijn said everything :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not dangerous if you secure access to database. You are exposing only your know-how. Once somebody gains access to database, it's easy to list database structure.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I concern is that there seem always to be security hole to leak access to my database, so I am thinking hiding column names will be a save a lot of efforts in securing access?

Comment: @FrostNovaZzz: If someone can use a SQL injection attack, they can query your database structure. Not knowing the structure won't prevent a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is dangerous, as if  a SQL injection vulnerability exists in your website, the scheme will help the attacker to retrieve all important data easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between sharing database and database schema.
You can comment the values of database machine/username/password in your code and publish the code on github.
As a proof of concept, you can host your application on cloud(without disclosing its database credentials) and add its link to your github readme file.